Are there limits to "Progressive Revelation" regarding the nature of God?
Background
Christians commonly hold that God revealed the truth progressively in history in areas of theology like the plan of salvation and law. Many Christians also believe that the Triune nature of God was revealed progressively over time, and that early men may not have understood God to be a Trinity but the Trinity was revealed slowly with "increasing clarity as more and more of the Scriptures were written".
Question
Given that Christians believe God has revealed different aspects of his nature over time, do any Christian denominations believe there are limits to "progressive revelation"? Specifically, could God reveal new information about his nature in the future such as another person? Or is the understanding of his nature now considered fully complete?

@NigelJ updated to not be opinion based


Do any Christian denominations believe there are limits to "progressive revelation"?

It would be good to precisely unpack this concept of "progressive revelation", in terms of 1) WHO is doing the revealing, 2) WHAT is being revealed, 3) HOW it is revealed (i.e. who are the recipients in the history of humankind), and 4) the CONTRAST between "new information" and "new understanding" within "progressive revelation".
The mainstream branches of Christianity (Protestant denominations, the Roman Catholic Church, and the Eastern Orthodox churches) agree that the Three of the Trinity are the ones doing the revealing, with different kinds of effects seen from our side of humankind:

The Father through His authorized messengers in the OT: angels, sanctioned prophets, inspired authors of the Hebrew Bible.

The Son through the Word's incarnation in Jesus showed God in human form in living contact (in the flesh) with the 12 Apostles, as well as later in their lifetimes (in his Holy Spirit).

The Holy Spirit working in the church: guiding the writing of the NT, the reflection of the early church fathers culminating in the councils, and the closing of the canon by designating that set of books as the only ones containing the written Word of God (Scripture).


But throughout the 2,000 years history of Christianity so far, the reflection of what God has been doing in the Church continues, as competing visions and understandings of the gospel meet new situations, new religions (now in the age globalization these come from the Far East), and new challenges (such as from archaeology, science, new philosophies, new interpretations).  All 3 mainstream branches then

generate new theologies (which we can call "traditions") to codify these reflections (usually they wouldn't appeal to God in writing these), one example being the recent New Perspective on Paul which modifies earlier understanding law vs. gospel, justification, and covenant,
attribute the Holy Spirit as guiding the churches to keep preserving the Bible & the "catholic" Apostolic Tradition (with a capital "T") articulated in the early church, and
believe the Holy Spirit to guide their official periodic church denominational meetings (Protestants) / church councils (Catholics & Orthodox) which issue new binding confessions or documents to guide their members until today.

What differs in these 3 branches is the PROCESS they use to reflect on Scripture and on this "catholic" Apostolic Tradition:

Most Protestants adamantly subject their "traditions" (Reformed, Lutheran, Anglican, etc.) to Scripture (sola scriptura); so no new information at all, only new understandings. For these Protestants those traditions are categorically different than "progressive revelation" because these are purely human undertaking without ascribing God to any aspect of it. Even the Holy Spirit-led process leading to confessions / documents issued at denominational conventions (which are binding for their denomination), do NOT see those documents as new "information" either.
But many 20th and 21st century charismatics would add prophecies and even apostolic authority (such as NAR) to serve as additional "word from God" (this is their terminology) mostly to individuals, thus new "information".  They say that these prophecies / "apostolic covering" are subject to Scripture, only to supplement when Scripture is silent, mostly in the areas of PERSONAL situation of individual believers as they decipher God's will for their life (career, spouse, family, etc.) and secondly, in the areas of individual CHURCH-WIDE direction (for ministering to their congregations and for missions).  I think it's fair to see these as a subtype of "progressive revelation".

Catholics see a living tradition on par with Scripture and supports the notion of doctrinal development, hence the late arrival of the Marian dogmas.  So to what's for Protestants a relatively final Apostolic Tradition, Catholics would add new "information", such as the documents from the latest ecumenical 2nd Vatican Council.  I think it's fair to see this as another subtype of "progressive revelation" although they wouldn't call it "revelation".

I don't know too much about Eastern Orthodoxy.  Although they seem to close off the possibility of doctrinal development they heighten the authority of the early church tradition to subsume Scripture under it.  Also, the content is larger than the Apostolic Tradition that Protestants accept (i.e. as codified in the Apostle's and Nicene Creeds) to include their doctrine of Icons, for example.  Again, they would distinguish tradition from "revelation".



Specifically, could God reveal new information about his nature in the future such as another person?  Or is the understanding of his nature now considered fully complete?

Notice how the CONTENT of the subtypes of "progressive revelation" described above is purposefully limited to reflections on subjects OTHER than the nature of God.  To them, the nature of God was already definitive by the time of the Council of Chalcedon.  Even prior to Chalcedon, this Trinitarian processing of the nature of God did NOT use any additional "information" revealed to a person OTHER than to the 12 apostles or to the writers of the New Testament.  So in one sense, this "understanding" can be considered "complete" by Chalcedon.  So to those adopting this view today, same information, same understanding.
But some evangelicals and other Christians uncomfortable with certain traditional understandings of God accumulated since Chalcedon, such as Divine Simplicity, God being completely outside time, psychological analogies of the Trinity, etc, would generate new theologies about the nature of God such as Open Theism, Process Theology (God doesn't know the future), Social Trinitarianism, Karl Rahner's view that the immanent Trinity IS the economic Trinity, etc.  So they would not agree that the traditional "understanding" is definitive and is open to new "understanding".  Even so, they would definitely NOT appeal to any new "information" revealed to another person.  Therefore, same information, new understanding.
We must now include some Christian groups, most notably the Latter Day Saints church, that allow "new information" about God's nature to be progressively revealed to another person, namely to Joseph Smith in the 19th century.  So their position is: new information, new understanding.  That is the core reason why they reject the mainstream's concept of the Trinity.  I think it's fair to say that for them this "progressive revelation" is continuing through the official Prophets of their church (who are also their church leaders).
Conclusion
"Progressive revelation" covers a broad area of newer "information" as well as newer "understanding" of God and His salvation message and actions for humankind (such as the covenants and providence), as well as many other topics related to the true wisdom for living, laws, origin and history of Israel, etc., evident in the Hebrew Bible and for Christians, continuing into the New Testament.
On the nature of God, which is a subset of that revelation, the 3 mainstream branches processed it this way:

the new "information" stopped with Jesus
the high prophetical living contact with God (through the Holy Spirit) stopped with the 12 apostles as they processed within their lifetimes the impact and meaning of their experience with the historical Jesus
Scriptural encoding of that living contact stopped with writing of the New Testament (inspired for inerrancy by the Holy Spirit)

But new propositional "understanding" for the sake of clarity (which should be "downstream" and reverent to the 12 Apostles's living contact with the mystery of God) continues until the Council of Chalcedon, which became part of the Apostolic Tradition.  One good discussion of this post-scriptural processing of the nature of God can be heard in minutes 3:17-10:30 of Tough Trinity Questions (media player here).

this answer is quite strong, thank you

@AviAvraham Thanks.  Feel free to add (relevant) follow up questions in the comment, and I'll edit the answer further.

It's worth noting that the vast majority of Christians believe the canon is closed. In other words, there is nothing further to be revealed regarding God's nature and plan of salvation. See this question for a discussion of the topic (though I admit I haven't looked at the answers myself).
Setting that aside, probably the most significant restriction to progressive revelation is that new revelation cannot contradict previous revelation. This follows from God's attributes including omniscience, immutability, etc.
Taking your example, Trinitarian Christians don't believe that the Trinity as revealed in the New Testament contradicts Old Testament revelation. The doctrine may not have been revealed so completely and may not have been understood by Old Testament believers, but we see hints at both one and more-than-one right from the very first chapter of Genesis. While the NT doesn't explicitly state "no more than three", unless you accept the long version of 1 John 5:7 (I personally do, but wouldn't cite it as a proof text knowing the dispute), the "threeness" is clear enough throughout texts such as 2 Cor. 13:14 that I'd view adding a fourth person as a definite contradiction.

Up-voted +1. 'new revelation cannot contradict previous revelation'.

The history of Israel is the history of the progressive revelation of God himself : as Creator, as the Most High, as Judge, as Shepherd, as Defender, as Redeemer, and as Reward. 'I am thy shield and thine exceeding great reward,' Genesis 15:1.
But this was progressive ; in Adam, in Abel, in Enoch, in Noah, in Job, in Elihu, in Abraham, in Isaac, in Jacob, in Joseph, in Moses, in Joshua, in the Judges, in Samuel and in all the prophets.
A progressive revelation of whom and what God is. 'I am that I am.' Exodus 3:14.
Thus is revealed, God himself, to those who receive that progress of instruction and that imparting of wisdom and knowledge, through others. Those others being those persons specifically chosen of God to express his words to yet more, that he, himself, might be apprehended and be worshipped.
The progress was charted out in prophecy before the progress occurred.
A seed promised, of woman (not of man) in the very beginning ; 'God will provide,' stated to young Isaac on the mount ; 'To thee will I give it,' spoken of the whole world to Abraham ; 'The Lord said unto my Lord - Sit thou,' spoken in David. Genesis 3:15 ; Genesis 22:8 ; Genesis 13:15 ; Psalm 110:1. Incarnation ; substitutionary sacrifice ; redemption ; ascension.
Verse upon verse, chapter by chapter, the prophecies mark out a future revelation before it even happens.
The great problem with Israel, was, however, that they did not receive what they already had.
They persecuted prophets, and slew them, Acts 7:52. They chided with God in the wilderness, and they fell as carcasses in the desert, Heb 3:17. Some rebelled and the ground itself swallowed them up, Num 16:32.
Both Israel and Judah behaved so badly that both were taken captive ; one recovered, the other not. Assyria, then Babylon.
They did not progress.
They did not build, line upon line, precept upon precept, here a little, there a little, Isaiah 28:10. . . .  as a little child weaned of its mother, Psalm 131:2.
Israel stumbled. And Israel fell. Romans 11:11.
Therefore, the revelation of the New Testament is that another humanity altogether is that which arises to take over the kingdom of the heavens. A humanity not of flesh and blood, John 1:13. A seed not of Adam, nor of Abraham, Matthew 3:9.
'Ye must be born again' is the revelation of the New Testament, John 3:3.
And if that is rejected, then everything is rejected. No further progress can be made.
And it is hypothetical to talk of 'further revelation' when any step on the way has faltered and one has turned aside.
'Progress' when one has ceased to progress, is just a supposition. A mere speculation.
Only those who have learned of the Father, John 6:45, make the progress that is utterly essential in the progression of revelation.
Not to discover God as 'Father' (with all that that implies of the begetting of the Son and that begetting of sons by Holy Spirit which is through  word) is to falter and fail at the most crucial of all stages.
Indeed, all previous 'progress' will collapse if that step is not taken. 'For he that hath, to him shall be given: and he that hath not, from him shall be taken even that which he hath,' Mark 4:25.
The new birth, once experienced, is that which brings the revelation of three Persons sharing one Divine nature, Matthew 28:19. The Father draws, the Spirit reveals and the Son is known. Thus, is the soul saved.
And they who enter in this strait gate and who progress upon this narrow way discover that all is, now, revealed, Matthew 7:14.
They find a fulness, Ephesians 3:19.
A completeness, Colossians 2:10.
The journey is done.
Everything is revealed.
And now ?
Come, Lord Jesus, come. Revelation 22:20.
(For all is fulfilled.)
This is the message of the New Testament.

The fact is that all Christian gatherings, that I know of, profess most sincerely and most absolutely, that all is revealed and the progression is accomplished and that our activity is to wait for the Lord to appear from heaven, whence we shall see him as he is . . . . .  the final revelation being his physical appearance : as he ascended, in the same manner he cometh, Acts 1:11.
Of others it is written . . . 'ever learning and never able to come to the knowledge of the truth,' 2 Timothy 3:7.


That Christ may dwell in your hearts by faith; that ye, being rooted and grounded in love, May be able to comprehend with all saints what is the breadth, and length, and depth, and height; And to know the love of Christ, which passeth knowledge, that ye might be filled with all the fulness of God.  [Ephesians 3:17,18 KJV]


All quotations and references are from the KJV which is translated from the Textus Receptus.
